# Radio button onclick change the view in android

Tags: android, image

I have two radio buttons namely once and daily.When I click once it will load one image and when I click another button it will show another static image.Its all work fine. I designed the radio button with image loading by getting id of the radio button and set background resource. But now I am confused about how to configure the image with edit text and button fields.Can anyone help me to accomplish this task?

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        if (checkedId == R.id.once) {
              int imageId = (Integer) once.getTag();

                imgview.setBackgroundResource(imageId);

        } else if (checkedId == R.id.daily) {
             int imageId = (Integer) daily.getTag();

                imgview.setBackgroundResource(imageId);

        } 
    }
```

This is my code.Now my requirement is to want to access edittext field and button field in image which was loaded when radio button is clicked.

Comment: kindly post your code.

Comment: Cant understand your question. Can you please brief it?

Comment: and what the issue in accessing edittext & button field?

Comment: Actually i have radio buttons once and daily.When i click once one image could be loaded same for daily button.Now the image which was loaded have to contain textview and button.When i click that button it will show picker.Now u guys understood?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've completely understood your question.
You want to show/hide a textview and a button instead of an Image?

If so, simply create a LinearLayout containing a textview and a button, then set the attribute

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

in the LinearLayout tag.

Then via code you can set its visibility with:

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE / View.GONE)
```

If this doesn't answer your question please give us more details

Comment: I have edited my post if u are still confused means let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this if you have the ids,

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    if (checkedId == R.id.once) {
          int imageId = (Integer) once.getTag();

            imgview.setBackgroundResource(imageId);
            EditText et = (EditText) imgview.findViewById(R.id.textFieldId);
            Button btn = (Button) imgview.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);

    } else if (checkedId == R.id.daily) {
         int imageId = (Integer) daily.getTag();

            imgview.setBackgroundResource(imageId);
            EditText et = (EditText) imgview.findViewById(R.id.textFieldId);
            Button btn = (Button) imgview.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
    } 
}
```

Otherwise you can use

```
EditText et = (EditText) imgview.getChildAt(0);
Button btn = (Button) = (Button ) imgview.getChildAt(1);
```

If you don't have the ids, pay attention to the order in which you have created the views

**HOW TO MODIFY Linear Layout Background**

Put this into the onCheckedChanged, in the if or in the else block, depending on your needs:

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE/View.GONE);
ll.setBackgroundResource(imageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code that works perfectly for me :

```
// declare your vars 
ImageView imgView;
Bitmap bitmap1,bitmap2;

// in your constructor do the following……
// load your bitmaps here
bitmap1 =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bitmap1);
bitmap2 =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bitmap2);

// init your image view
showImageView = new Imageview(getContext());


// AND IN YOUR LISTENER 
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkId){
    if(checkedId == R.id.once){
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
    }else if(checkedId == R.id.daily){
        imgView.setImageDrawable(bitmap2);
    }
}
```